# R Summarize"Yes" if all columns are "Yes"

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(Subject = c("A","B","C"),
          Col1 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No"),
          Col2 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes"),
          Col3 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes")
                   )

print(data)

 Subject Col1 Col2 Col3
1       A  Yes  Yes  Yes
2       B  Yes  Yes  Yes
3       C   No  Yes  Yes
```

I want to summarize whether all of the columns equal "Yes. If so, new column is "Yes", if one of the columns are `NA` or "No", then summary column is "No".

My current code looks something like this, but I feel like there is an easier way:

```
data %>%
group_by(Subject) %>%
summarize(Summary = case_when(
    Col1 == "Yes & Col2 == "Yes & Col3 == "Yes ~ "Yes",
    Col1 != "Yes & Col2 != "Yes & Col3 != "Yes ~ "No",
    TRUE ~ NA
```

Comment: The data frame provided is a simple reprex. I need to select columns 3:12 of the actual data frame. I revised my code to the following, but I think I am not implementing `select` properly.


`mutate(Summary= if_else(rowSums(select(3:12) != "Yes") > 0, "No", "Yes")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the suggestions. Here is the solution I am moving forward with:

```
data %>%
   mutate(Summary = if_else(rowSums(.[c(2:4)]!="Yes")>0,"No", "Yes"))
```

*Note, I substituted `.c[3:12]` for `.c[2:4]` for my actual data frame.

Answer (score 5):

We may use `if_all/if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
 mutate(Summary = case_when(if_all(starts_with("Col"), 
     ~. == "Yes") ~ "Yes", TRUE ~ "No"))
```

-output

```
 Subject Col1 Col2 Col3 Summary
1       A  Yes  Yes  Yes     Yes
2       B  Yes  Yes  Yes     Yes
3       C   No  Yes  Yes      No
```

Comment: Nice use of `if_all`, I haven't worked them into my daily rituals yet.

Answer (score 3):

```r
data %>%
  mutate(newcol = rowSums(select(cur_data(), starts_with("Col")) != "Yes") == 0)
#   Subject Col1 Col2 Col3 newcol
# 1       A  Yes  Yes  Yes   TRUE
# 2       B  Yes  Yes  Yes   TRUE
# 3       C   No  Yes  Yes  FALSE
```

That gets you a simple `logical` column, in general when a column is a truth-like property, I prefer `logical`. If you want that to be literal strings, though, then

```r
data %>%
  mutate(newcol = if_else(rowSums(select(cur_data(), starts_with("Col")) != "Yes") == 0, "Yes", "No"))
#   Subject Col1 Col2 Col3 newcol
# 1       A  Yes  Yes  Yes    Yes
# 2       B  Yes  Yes  Yes    Yes
# 3       C   No  Yes  Yes     No
```

As I learn dplyr's more "recent" verbs (relatively speaking), akrun's recommendation to use `if_all` makes a lot more sense here, where the above can be done more succinctly as

```r
data %>%
  mutate(newcol = if_else(if_all(starts_with("Col"), ~ . == "Yes"), "Yes", "No"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, in `base R`:

```r
data$Summary <- rowSums((data[-1] != "Yes")) == 0
data

#>   Subject Col1 Col2 Col3 Summary
#> 1       A  Yes  Yes  Yes    TRUE
#> 2       B  Yes  Yes  Yes    TRUE
#> 3       C   No  Yes  Yes   FALSE
```

Comment: As a suggested alternative to this: this code relies on their being exactly 3 columns; if you change from `== "Yes"` to `!= "Yes"`, one can compare then with `== 0` and be more agnostic to the number of `Col#` columns. Just a thought :-)

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans, for having commented my solution! You are right! I have just updated my solution accordingly.

Comment: Now, it is right, @r2evans!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(data)

dt[, Summary := fifelse(dt[, Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `!=`, "Yes")), .SDcols = -1] == 0, "Yes", "No")]
```

**Output**

```
   Subject Col1 Col2 Col3 Summary
1:       A  Yes  Yes  Yes     Yes
2:       B  Yes  Yes  Yes     Yes
3:       C   No  Yes  Yes      No
```